# How to change the developer's info

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How do I change the developer's email that a new user gets when they sign-up for my site? See image below..

[image]

Will I have to completely set up a new firebase account with a different email address and change all the code corresponding with this one? Or is there another way?

Comment: It looks like you're using Firebase for building a web app. In that case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The email I blacked out is my email that I used to set-up firebase with. I would rather have a generic email address showing here vs my personal one. How do I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want your project to be associated with a different email, correct? If that's what you mean, then you can go to the Firebase console, click the gear>Users and Permissions, add the other email as the owner, accept the role with the other email, and then delete the original email you no longer want to associate.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Don't know why I couldn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: What should I do, if I want to keep two or more ids as owners? Any other approach in this case?

Comment: following the step did not solve the issue. Additional steps were required which i am adding as a separate solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74091850/6840615

Answer (score 5):

Email id and all the other information that is appearing under **Developer info** popup can be changed in **OAuth consent screen**.

Here is the path:

"https://console.cloud.google.com/" -> "**APIs & Services**" -> "**Credentials**" -> "**OAuth consent screen**"

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the google login is setup through firebase then the developer's email shown on the popup can be updated by the following setps(shown by green marking in the diagram below):

- Firebase console
- Click the gear > Project settings
- Select the General tab, under Public settings > update support email

Addition to that can be confirmed by following the step shown in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864875/6840615)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow the steps below:

- Go to project settings
  [image]
- Add a new member
  [image]
- Complete the new member setup
- From the General tab under Public settings you can choose the newly added member.[image]